# Using a phone to give internet access to an already established network

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, hardware, internet

I am currently planning a project I wish to undertake in the next few months, a power bank / portable file server / wifi router. I want to be able to give internet access to devices connected to the wifi network using my phone (rooted).

Client -> wifi router project -> my phone -> Internet via mobile data

My phone would also be a client on the network. I would be using a raspberry pi zerow inside the project.

Wondering if this is at all possible, and if it is, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: This should be fairly easy but I don't see how it is Android related... This would all be on the RPi, I would recommend a simple Linux installation and just USB tether or add a second WiFi adapter to the RPi to tether to the phone via WiFi. Nothing would need to be done special on the phone.

Comment: Just not sure about how I'd share Internet access from my phone, as I would be using mobile hot-spot, phone would be connected to rpi wifi

Comment: Like I said... You would either USB tether it or use a second WiFi connection on the RPi (via a USB dongle probably). You can't easily use the built in WiFi module of a RPi by itself to link to the outside world AND provide WiFi simultaneously.